# AWK Sentence doing looping for in the code to capitalize some fields

Tags: awk, toupper, tolower

The code

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1))tolower(substr($i,2));}print}'
```

I need to capitalize the first character of every word in some fields.
This loop look for all the characters in the lines and replace the first charcater in the line and do the tolower sentence for the rest of the line if its not in the first place of the field.
I need some example of this loop but assigning the sentence only for some field (one or more) please make an explanation of the answer and how it does work on the all the line and field.

I haved viewed without loop doing this.

```
awk '{print toupper(substr($0,1,1))tolower(substr($0,2))}'
```

The tolower part take all the line and if I change by some field for example the number 2:

```
$>  echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD Eeee Ffff Gggg HHHH'  | awk '{print toupper(substr($0,1,1)) tolower(substr($2,2)) }'

$>  Abbb
```

The $0 tells to do toupper to all the line for the first char, the following part ($0)(,1,1) tells its for only one char, and last specify the lenght of this doing (1) but the tolower part said it take from the 2nd char of the field 2 and print together (because the statements are sticked) 
Please tell me if im wrong in some of this and the explanation hoping understanably.

I expect to do the sentence of Toupper of Tolower specifying the field to want to do this.

Example of what it´s expected:

Do the capitalize only to the field 4 and 8 in this space separated like before showed or in other example if I have and semicolon separated field how to do this, example:

```
>$ echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH'
```

Do the same in the 4th word of the field 1 and the 2nd in the 3rd field. (now the fields are semicolon separated)

Resulting:

```
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd;Eeee Ffff;Gggg Hhhh
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, but I didn't understand your expected  output or question so please do add samples of output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @ed-morton, Only want the explanation how to do this and how it´s work for this reason haved spended the time showing my thoughts about the code, sorry for the post quick.. im new in here, im learing ...

Comment: @Ed Morton I understand there are a million of ways to do the same, and its really hard to explain all the cases, I think if I undestand the sentence and how it works I can shape the answer to make it does what I want to do. The question may help somebody there to shortcut if have to do some like this. I didnt finded the answer in stack before.

Comment: @EdMorton As allways Thank you.. you helped me only to tell me how to do the  question.

Comment: do you have to use _awk_? or other bash commands allows?

Comment: @Hossein Vatani the goal here its to do this in awk, but if you have some way to do in bash, are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Do the same in the 4th word of the field 1 and the 2nd in the 3rd field.` and the other answers and some of the other text and examples in your question suggest you want to change selected space-separated sub fields of selected semi-colon separated fields to start with upper case and then be all lower case, here's one approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(nrs,tmp,/[ .]+/)
    for (i=1; i in tmp; i+=2) {
        tgtFldNrs[++numTgts]  = tmp[i]
        tgtSubFldNrs[numTgts] = tmp[i+1]
    }
    FS = OFS = ";"
    subFs = subOfs = " "
}
{
    for (tgtNr=1; tgtNr<=numTgts; tgtNr++) {
        fldNr    = tgtFldNrs[tgtNr]
        subFldNr = tgtSubFldNrs[tgtNr]

        numSubFlds = split($fldNr,subFlds,subFs)
        subFld = subFlds[subFldNr]
        subFlds[subFldNr] = toupper(substr(subFld,1,1)) tolower(substr(subFld,2))

        fld = subFlds[1]
        for (subFldNr=2; subFldNr<=numSubFlds; subFldNr++) {
            fld = fld subOfs subFlds[subFldNr]
        }
        $fldNr = fld
    }

    print
}
```

Given this sample input:

```
$ cat file
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH
```

telling awk to update sub-field 4 of field 1 (`1.4`) and sub-field 2 of field 3 (`3.2`) (from `Do the same in the 4th word of the field 1 and the 2nd in the 3rd field` in the question) it will output:

```
$ awk -v nrs='1.4 3.2' -f tst.awk file
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd;Eeee Ffff;Gggg Hhhh
```

Hopefully that's what you're trying to do, if not then please update your question to clarify your requirements and provide more comprehensive sample input/output.

Comment: So you pass in the *file.word* pairs to operate on rather than taking the total filed count using alternative separators. I guess for generic input that is the way to go. Otherwise, it ends up tailored to the example input rather than the generic instructions. Thanks again for the pointers and help.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah I took that final sentence from the question of `Do the same in the 4th word of the field 1 and the 2nd in the 3rd field.` as the real crux of the requirements.

Comment: @EdMorton I dint haved  tried  the code  yet but in the second condition  have a strage output it have gived output all the first field up to the semicolon  repeting the fourth word in the field. Changing Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd; for  Dddd Dddd Dddd Dddd; this 1.4 telled to nrs are replacing the original content,  And the same for the 3.2 ir replaced Gggg Hhhh by Hhhh Hhhh I will test it  anyways.

Comment: @EDMorton Now haved tested and works even if have RE metachars if you have some time please explain the code, again thanks.

Comment: @User1234141414 You're welcome. I always try to use variable names and a layout that'd make my code self-explanatory so please take a look and let me know if there's any part of it where you can't understand what it's doing.

Comment: @EDMorton had taked your variable name passed as "awk -v nrs" to the same inside the awk code as nrs="1.1.. etc" to simplify the execution. may be is a little improve.

Comment: That makes it so you can no longer call the script from the command line or from a shell script and tell it to operate on different fields as you're now hard-coding it in the script. If you want a script that can only change one specific list of hard-coded fields then sure that'd be a way to do it, but otherwise it's not what you'd want.

Comment: You are right.. but have some problems with the single quotes in scripting so the scripts may fail in the call, and I had thought the way to do one dynamic change of this field selection, only need to find "nrs=...." in the code and replace by the desired fields to later the code that you made do the rest.

Comment: You should debug whatever problems you have with single quotes in scripting because those are what you should be using everywhere by default in shell scripts around all strings and scripts. Obviously in this case you could use `-v nrs="..."` instead of `-v nrs='...'` in the call to awk but whatever works for you...

Answer (score 4):

Or you can turn it around and convert the entire line to lowercase and then loop over the fields converting the first-character to uppercase, e.g.

```
awk '{
    sub($0,tolower($0))
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        sub(substr($i,1,1),toupper(substr($i,1,1)))
}1'
```

At the end the `'1'` just provides a default print of the entire line.

**Example Use/Output**

Just paste it into your terminal, e.g.

```
$ echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD Eeee Ffff Gggg HHHH' |
> awk '{
>     sub($0,tolower($0))
>     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
>         sub(substr($i,1,1),toupper(substr($i,1,1)))
> }1'
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd Eeee Ffff Gggg Hhhh
```

**Using Alternative Field Separators**

Per your edit to your question, if you have alternate field separators of `"[ ;]"` you can specify the alternative separators with a character list in gawk, or by OR'ing the separators, e.g.

```
awk -F'[ ;]' '{
    sub($0,tolower($0))
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        sub(substr($i,1,1),toupper(substr($i,1,1)))
}1'
```

Testing with your revised input results in the following, e.g.

```
$ echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH' |
> awk -F'[ ;]' '{
>     sub($0,tolower($0))
>     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
>         sub(substr($i,1,1),toupper(substr($i,1,1)))
> }1'
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd;Eeee Ffff;Gggg Hhhh
```

**Only Affecting The 4th and 8th Fields**

Though not asked directly, it is unclear whether you want to modify all fields, or just the 4th and 8th fields under some circumstances. If you only want to change the 4th and 8th fields, leaving the rest alone, you can add the `modulo` check I referred to in a previous edit to isolate only those fields. For example:

```
awk -F'[ ;]' '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            sub($i,tolower($i))
            sub(substr($i,1,1),toupper(substr($i,1,1)))
        }
    }
}1'
```

In this case, all other fields would be left unchanged and the 4th and 8th converted to Titlecase, e.g.

```
$ echo 'aaaa bbbb cccc DDDD;eeee ffff;gggg HHHH' |
> awk -F'[ ;]' '{
>     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
>         if (i % 4 == 0) {
>             sub($i,tolower($i))
>             sub(substr($i,1,1),toupper(substr($i,1,1)))
>         }
>     }
> }1'
aaaa bbbb cccc Dddd;eeee ffff;gggg Hhhh
```

If this doesn't cover it all, just let me know.

Comment: David haved updated the question, sorry I had errors telling the expecting result.

Comment: Oh OK, let me look at that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, howdy sir, how about this generic one https://stackoverflow.com/a/57379358/5866580

Comment: @User1234141414 - sorry about the confusion. As you had it first written, it looked as if you intended to convert the 4th and 8th fields to uppercase rather than just dealing with the alternative field separators.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - I like that one too. Though I'm still a bit confused on exactly what is being described with all the edits adding a few pieces at a time. From the last edit it looks like he wishes to preserve the alternative field separators in the output. That's my best guess `:)`

Comment: In [POSIX terminology](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) `[ ;]` is a bracket expression containing a character list, not a character class. A character class would be, for example `[:space:]` which could also be contained in a bracket expression as `[[:space:]]`. FWIW I like the approach of making every char lower case first, assuming the OP does want to convert all words and not just a specific subset of them.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton. I will tighten the list/class language. I have ham-fistedly referred to both as character class for a long time (ones you create yourself and ones that a pre-defined). So we create a list and POSIX provides classes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 many thanks for your patience! I will test all the answers and will try to understand how it works testing it.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there's a whole other RE terminology out there that idk where it comes from but it's used extensively in https://www.regular-expressions.info and in that terminology the term "character class" seems to refer to both a POSIX bracket expression and a POSIX character class. [They explain it](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) as `POSIX bracket expressions are a special kind of character classes.` - ugh. Any time you use the word "special" or "new" in software you know you've gone off the rails. I stick to POSIX terminology as there's one term per concept!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that `sub()`s approach will fail when any of the strings contain RE metachars or backreferences.

Comment: That's a good observation. Then what about a `sprintf ("%s", ....)` to take the results of `tolower/toupper` for the cases we don't know the input with the use of a temporary variable or two?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you have in mind with that but I can't think of any way it'd help fix `sub(anything,anything)` if `anything` contains metachars. You should really stick to string functions unless you **need* regexp functions for a specific purpose.

Comment: FWIW I THINK what you might want to do is this: instead of `sub($i,tolower($i))` do `$i=tolower($i)` and instead of `sub(substr($i,1,1),toupper(substr($i,1,1))` do `$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1) substr($i,2)`. Of course you can combine those to `$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1) tolower(substr($i,2))`. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378830/awk-sentence-doing-looping-for-in-the-code-to-capitalize-some-fields/57379358?noredirect=1#comment101245152_57379358) to @RavinderSingh13 for another issue with using sub()s on the whole record as you're doing. But again, I'm guessing...

Comment: That makes sense. I had toyed with that but hadn't been able to preserve the alternative separators in the output. I'll circle back and try and figure out why. Thank you again @EdMorton.

Comment: Using a single character list as the separator you'd have to use GNU awk for the 4th arg to split() to preserve them and then operator in the resulting arrays rather than on the `$1`, etc. fields.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. I tried to make very Generic solution where we can mention field values where we need to make first character as UPPER case and rest as LOWER case.

```
echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH WEEEEEwrwr' | 
awk -v convert="4,8,9" '
BEGIN{
  FS="[; ]"
  num=split(convert,array,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    found[array[i]]
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i in found){
      first=substr($i,1,1)
      second=substr($i,2)
      sub(first,toupper(first))
      sub(second,tolower(second))
    }
  }
}
1'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd Eeee Ffff Gggg Hhhh Weeeeewrwr
```

I have extended your example here(by adding 1 more test value), also you could mention all field numbers in `-v convert=":4,8,9...."` in comma separated form to change them.

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code, it is for explanation purposes only, I haven't run it to check if that runs along with comments too.

```
echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH WEEEEEwrwr' |      ##Printing strings with echo and sending its output to awk command.
awk -v convert="4,8,9" '                                         ##Starting awk program here and creating variable named convert whose value will be all fields where we need to make the changes with comma separated.
BEGIN{                                                           ##Starting BEGIN section here.
  FS="[; ]"                                                      ##Setting FS field separator as semi colon OR space here for all lines.
  num=split(convert,array,",")                                   ##splitting convert variable to array whose delimiter is comma.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                                           ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of num(which is total number of elements in array, above created)
    found[array[i]]                                              ##Creating array named found whose index is value of array[i].
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                                            ##Starting a for loop from value of 1 to till NF.
    if(i in found){                                              ##Checking if current field is same field which user wants to change, if yes then go ahead with further statements.
      first=substr($i,1,1)                                       ##Creating variable first whose value is 1st character of current field.
      second=substr($i,2)                                        ##Creating variable first whose value is from 2nd field to till complete value of current field.
      sub(first,toupper(first))                                  ##using sub for changing first to UPPER case.
      sub(second,tolower(second))                                ##using sub for changing second to LOWER case.
    }
  }
}
1'                                                               ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197588/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-awk-sentence-doing-looping-for-in-the-co).

Answer (score 3):

You can try Perl like below

```
$ echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH WEEEEEwrwr' | 
perl -0777 -nE ' @a=qw(4 8 9);%k = map {$_,1} @a; s/(\w+)/$i++; $k{$i}==1 ? "\u\L$1":$1/ge; print'
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd;Eeee Ffff;Gggg Hhhh Weeeeewrwr
```

or one more way

```
$ echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc DDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH WEEEEEwrwr' | 
perl -0777 -nE ' @a=qw(4 8 9);@k{@a}=undef; s/(\w+)/$i++; exists $k{$i} ? "\u\L$1":$1/ge ; print '
Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd;Eeee Ffff;Gggg Hhhh Weeeeewrwr
```

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to done with `sed`:

```
  echo 'Aaaa Bbbb Cccc dDDD;Eeee Ffff;Gggg HHHH' | sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z]{1})([a-zA-Z]+)/\U\1\L\2/g'
```

to explain:

1. `-r`: used for *extended regular experssion*
2. `'s/.../.../'`: stand for *substitution*
3. `([a-zA-Z]{1})`: find *first character* of word
4. `([a-zA-Z]+)`: the rest of word
5. `\U,\L`: operators to change the character case
6. `\1...\9`: indicates the pattern which finds in the search part.

hope useful.